How to add airflow in my existing docker?
version: '3.8'

services:
  jupyter:
    image: jupyter/pyspark-notebook
    container_name: jupyter-pyspark
    ports:
      - "8888:8888"
      - "4040:4040"
    volumes:
      - D:/pyspark/datasets:/home/jovyan/work
    environment:
      - JUPYTER_ENABLE_LAB=yes
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:7.5.0
    container_name: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  broker:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:7.5.0
    container_name: broker
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - "29092:29092"
      - "9092:9092"
      - "9101:9101"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://broker:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 0
      KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 9101
      KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: localhost
    networks:
      - mynetwork

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 12345678
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dev
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 12345678
    volumes:
      - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mynetwork

volumes:
  mysql_data:

networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge

I am working on setting up a Docker environment that integrates PySpark, Apache Airflow, Apache Kafka, and MySQL. Despite several attempts, I am encountering issues with initializing the services and ensuring they work together. Below is my docker-compose.yml configuration and details about the problems I am facing.

do you need zookeeper ? i think you should use kRaft, aslo your DB should run first , because the kafka is trying to connect to DB , where as DB is not initilaised or is taking time to start , it will give error , as per my knowledge , first run DB , so change and try this  Zookeeper depends upon DB ::: depends_on:
- mysql
